# Accessing child IDs within user IDs in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a firebase database with the following structure, with the top ID shown being a user's UID:

[image]
Although this example shows only 2 menu items, most of my users will have more than 10.  If I wanted to create a list of all of the menu item names, what would that query look like in Swift?  More specifically, what would that path look like in swift?  Currently, my path makes it this far:

```
var itemNameRef = Firebase(url: "https://*******.firebaseIO.com/users/\(ref.authData.uid)/menu/")
```

Is there an ID placeholder similar to authdata.uid which I can place in the space after "menu?

Previously and under a different structure, using a [for] loop I was able to get the item names stored as children under "menu",with item details stored beneath that. But based on advice from another SO user, I've swapped to random keys and am back to square one.

Am I doing this the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to understand what your problem is, but have a hard time. Why can't you simply use [`ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types)? I also noticed you've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing(tm) to do.

Comment: Couldn't you just loop through the values using your current path and create a new array from the itemNames?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll place the actual JSON in there next time, I didn't even know I could export it like that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query a list of menu item names as you have it now:

```
var rootRef = Firebase(url: "https://*******.firebaseIO.com")
let menuItems = rootRef.childByAppendingPath(UID).childByAppendingPath("menu")
menuItems.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for id in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

Also, for best practice, try to build a "flat" database structure for Firebase (see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html).

Comment: Thanks Julian! I'll have a look at that resource.